# Chrome Extension : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I'm new in chrome extension, I'm trying to develop a chrome extension that communicates with my python web API. It throws an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd4g6.png).

These are permissions in manifest.json:

```
 "background": {
     "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js","backgroundScript.js"],
     "persistent": true
 },
 "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "http://*/",
     "https://*/",
     "webNavigation",
     "*://*/*",
     "http://127.0.0.1:5000/*" 
 ]
```

This is ajax request in backgroundScript.js:

```
let obj = {
    "url": response
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/scrape_company", // URL de l'API
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    data: obj, 
    unique: true,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result=== obj["url"] + ': scrapped and inserted with success') {
            alert(result);
        } else{
            alert('Check your url !');
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Please wait until the scraping is done');
    }
});
```

And this is my popup.html :

```
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="backgroundScript.js"></script>
    
    <link href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/scrape_company">
 
    
  </head>
```

How can I communicate with  my web server? thanks in advance

Comment: The background script runs in a hidden background page and should be loaded only via manifest.json, not in popup.js. After you fix it make sure to click the reload icon for your extension on `chrome://extensions` page. See also [how to see background.js console?](/a/10258029). Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Are you sure that the ports match and the port is open?

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your reply, I omitted the  background script from popup but unfortunately it's the same error : connection refused

Comment: @Rojo sorry I'm new to all of that, how can I check if the port is open or not . and I have to note that I test it with postman before using the chrome extension and it worked fine

Comment: Could you try running your extension with Firefox? I feel that Firefox is better at debugging and having more descriptive errors. If you need help, you can let me know and I will start a private room.

Comment: Thank you @Rojo, the problem is that I have to work with chrome. Could you please help me in that  ?